# Can we have two launcher activity, one hidden and other as the app launcher activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

When we press home button, one cannot start an activity from service as specified in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4536). So i noticed that we can launch any application within 5 seconds after pressing home button, or there is no 5 seconds delay. So i was thinking to add an activity with category of launcher so that when we click on service it can launch activity instantly without any delay.

Question : Can we have two launcher activity in one app? if yes how to start that activity with category of launcher from service?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: No you cannot, You have one manifest file and you are allowed to start one activity on runtime.

Comment: You  can have more than one activity show on the launcher, however, I do not think that will help your issue. Generally it is bad practice to auto launch an activity from a service. User interaction should launch activities.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but it is not auto launch when user will press on service layout the activity will be launched. But the problem is when user press home button and within 5 seconds user taps on service layout the activity is opened after 5 seconds. So is there any solution to this?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `service layout`?